# why can i import negative numbers as int, but not as long int or other larger data types?

Tags: c

When I use `va_arg` to import e.g. `-1`, and I specify `int` as the datatype, it gets it without problem. But if I specify `long int`, `long long int` or `intmax_t`, it displays `4294967295`.

Had I specified `unsigned int`, this would have been understandable. But I'm specifying a signed data type that's even bigger than an int. How can I get this output?

```
va_arg(valist, int) -> -1 (OK)
va_arg(valist, long int) -> 4294967295 (???)
```

Comment: You have to use `int` and then cast it to `long`. `va_list` actually uses the size of the data type.

Comment: If you check e.g `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)`, are they the same? My guess is that they're not. And really, please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And perhaps refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: exactly, long is bigger, isn't it? and it's signed isn't it? so why wouldn't it be able to get a -1? unsigned data types can't have negative numbers, they will be translated to INT_MAX - value. But here it's a signed value that has space enough to store -1. So why is it changing it as if it was an unsigned data type?

Comment: (a) Show actual code so people can discuss it concretely, not from vague descriptions. (b) When you call a function, the arguments have specific types. If you did not declare those types in a function declaration with a prototype, they default to certain types according to the default argument promotions. When you use `va_arg` to get the argument values, the C standard specifies the behavior only if you provide a pointer to a compatible type. The C implementation uses the type to locate the data. It is not sufficient that the value be representable in the type; you must actually match types.

Answer (score 2):

`-1` is considered an `int` constant, according to the language definition.
If you want a `long int` constant, you need to append an L: `-1L`.

Comment: Actually, `-1` is a unary expression (C 2018 6.5.3 1), not a constant. The `-` character is a separate token and cannot be part of an integer constant (6.4.4.1 1). (This causes, for example, `-2147483648` to be a `long int` when `int` is 32 bits and `long int` is wider, because 217483648 is not representable in `int` even though −2147483648 is.)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `-1` has type `int` (since the constant `1` has type `int` and applying the `-` operator to it retains the type), so you must retrieve it from the variable argument list with that type.  If you attempt to use something like `long int`, you invoke undefined behavior because the types may not be the same size, i.e. you're pushing 4 bytes on the stack but are trying to read 8 bytes.

What probably happened in this case is that 4 bytes were read with all bits set ( the -1 you passed in) then 4 more bytes were read which were all 0.  Those 8 bytes interpreted with little endian byte ordering as an 8 bit `long` gives you the value you saw.  But again, this is undefined behavior.  If those next 4 bytes had been something besides 0s you would have gotten a different value.

If you had passed in `-1L` then you would need to use `long int`.

Comment: Actually, `-1` is a unary expression (C 2018 6.5.3 1), not a constant. The `-` character is a separate token and cannot be part of an integer constant (6.4.4.1 1). (This causes, for example, `-2147483648` to be a `long int` when `int` is 32 bits and `long int` is wider, because 217483648 is not representable in `int` even though −2147483648 is.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `int` and then (implicitly or explicitly) cast it to `long`. `va_arg` uses the size of the data type that you pass it, and trying to retrieve the wrong data type is undefined behavior.

Example:

```
long a = va_arg(ap, int);
```

Another option is to pass `-1L` to the function, and then call `va_arg` with `long`:

```
func(arg1, arg2, arg3, -1L);
```

Comment: but isn't -1 an int as well as a long int as well as a long long int?

Comment: @nightowl92 no.

Comment: @nightowl92 `-1` is only an `int`. `-1L` is a `long int`, and `-1LL` is a `long long int`.

Answer (score 1):

`1` is an integral literal with the type `int`. How do we know this? We check the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value
>   can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base
>   and which integer-suffix was used.
>
> [image: Table from the reference]

Strictly speaking `-1` is an expression which evaluates to an object of type `int` with the value `-1`.
If you explicitly want a type, you can use one of the given suffixes. If you want a `long` use `-1L`

Comment: Actually, `-1` is a unary expression (C 2018 6.5.3 1), not a constant or literal. The `-` character is a separate token and cannot be part of an integer constant (6.4.4.1 1). (This causes, for example, `-2147483648` to be a `long int` when `int` is 32 bits and `long int` is wider, because 217483648 is not representable in `int` even though −2147483648 is.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for the feedback.That is very interesting. Tried to add that in.